# How to create a separate Devise authentication for certain areas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

My app has a controller whose actions need to be cut off from authenticated users behind a special password.

One way to imagine it: regular users go about their business. Once in a while, an admin needs to enter his/her password to let the regular users access an area.

I have Devise authentication set up the normal way in my app, so all my users are authenticated.

How can I now set up a separate password so all calls to a controller result in a request for a special separate password?

Comment: Hi, I'm curious to know if my solution has worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

> One way to do it is introducing a simple authentication from scratch on top of Devise's authentication
>   using the `bcrypt` library .

You will need a new field in your `users` table to store the special password digest. So, create a new migration file and the below code to it:

```
def change
  add_column :users, :special_password, :digest
end
```

Add Bcrypt gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.12'
```

To your user model add the below line:

```
has_secure_special_password
```

Now in your special password authentication controller, use the below code to authenticate `current_user` with the `special_password`

```
if current_user.authenticate(params[:user][:special_password])
  session[:special_user_id] = current_user.id
end
```

Now in whichever controller actions you want to authenticate the user with the special password, Create a `before_action` filter and try to find the user by `session[:special_user_id]` and if user not found you may ask them to enter the `special_password`